# Software for drawing basic geometry

Tags: linux, software-rec, drawing

I'm looking for some software that I can use to draw simple geometric things like this:

[image: dot product]

Or even better:

[image: distance]

Does anyone know any software capable of drawing these things easily? I'm particularly interested in anything that works on Linux.

Comment: Are you looking for a GUI app to hand-draw stuff, or some kind of markup/script language to describe a drawing to a renderer?

Comment: _markup/script language to describe a drawing to a renderer_ is the nearest of the two.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could try [C.a.R](http://zirkel.sourceforge.net/doc_en/index.html). It's free, cross platform and open source.

> C.a.R. is a dynamic geometry program simulating compass and ruler
>   constructions and much more on a computer.

[image]

Comment: wow! and it support Latex! great! I just did a simple one ( http://e.nigma.be/archives/35 ), but the cool thing is that it is very easy to use! Thanks!

Comment: Glad you like it! BTW, that firefly problem is way over my head :)

Comment: Wow, the cool stuff you learn reading these questions...

Answer (score 7):

[GeoGebra](http://www.geogebra.org/): it comes in multiple languages, is easy to use but powerful, and can export to LaTeX, SVG and other formats. It also supports applets and other tools.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Inkscape. You can make straight lines, arcs, text at arbitrary angles, etc.  With layers, you might be able to make a shadow on a trapezoid like in that example.

Answer (score -2):

Powerpoint or sketchup. Might not be the best but works if you don't have anything better at hands.